# N-dimensional array indexing in Matlab : find array in middle

Tags: arrays, matlab

I am working with N-dimensional array and have a problem with the array indexing. I have a task to find an (N-1)-dimensional array in the middle N-dimensional array.

Let me explain in detail with 3D array. `A` is a 3-dimensional array that has split into groups. In each group, there are `b` - number of 2-dimensional arrays in the group. I have simulated it as:

```
b=5;
A=rand(2,2,20);
groups = reshape(A, size(A,1), size(A,2),b, []);
```

`groups` is 4-dimensional array, the 4-th dimension is a number of groups ( here it 4).

To find a middle in each group I have added the following loop:

```
for ii=1:size(groups,4)  % Loop over all groups/slices
     middle(:,:,ii) = groups(:,:,(w-1)/2+1,ii);  % 1 2 3 4 5 : the middle is 3
end
```

`middle` is 3-dimensional array that collects middle array in each group.

As you see in my example I have used `b=5`( odd number). My problem is with even number `b`.

I have tried to implement it as ( rewrite the loop above);

```
l=rem(w,2);
 for ii=1:size(groups,4)  % Loop over all groups/slices
     if l==1
         middle(:,:,ii) = groups(:,:,(w-1)/2+1,ii);  
     else
         middle(:,:,ii) = groups(:,:,(w-1)/2,ii);  
     end
 end
```

But it doesn't work. Matlab gives me an error in the line `l=rem(w,2);` 
Could you suggest to me how I can fix it? Is there another way to implement it?

Comment: Out of `1 2 3 4`, which one is the "middle"?

Comment: “Matlab gives me an error in the line `l=rem(w,2)`”. What is the error? The line seems fine to me.

Comment: @beaker I was thinking about it. I am going to take an average of 2 and 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `floor` of `ceil` to round the index to whichever element you want:

```
middle_index = floor((w-1)/2+1);
```

Here, the middle of 4 is 2, using `ceil` you’d pick index 3.

Next, you can extract the arrays in a single indexing operation:

```
middle = groups(:,:,middle_index,:);
```

Finally, use `squeeze` or `reshape` to get rid of the 3rd index:

```
middle = squeeze(middle);
```